# Make an image button change a different image on page

Tags: java, android, xml, android-widget

I have an image at the top of the page called *grid.png*. There are a series of image buttons below the image. I want each image button to change the image *grid* to a different image (ex. grida.png, gridtable.png, etc.). I currently have it so each image button changes to a different xml page with an identical layout but with a different image in the place of grid.

However, the image button action only works on the main xml page and not any of the other pages. How would I be able to make the buttons switch *grid* to a different image without switching pages or make the buttons on the other pages function in the same way they do in main.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the whole layout (you only need one), just change the contents of `ImageView` when one of your `ImageButton`s gets clicked:

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView); // your ImageView "grid"

// then do this for each of your buttons
findViewById(R.id.imgButton1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // set new content of ImageView here
            imageView.setImageResource/Drawable/Bitmap(...);
        }
    });
```